# asp.net insert an element by index into an arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to asp.net and i'm writing some code to learn about arraylist

```
al.Add((string)"asfsaf");
al[1] = "bcd";
al.TrimToSize();

Response.Write(al[1]);
```

from the above code, the line al[1] = "bcd"; is wrong, is arraylist support insert elements by index? if not, any other data structure can be replaced?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try .Insert() as below:

```
al.Insert(1, "bcd");
```

Comment: This will fail if the list contains no element.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You can't directly insert based on an index in a List, you can only Set(Modify)/Get a value to an index. **If it exists**

---

You can use indexing with an ArrayList as well, but use a Generic [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of ArrayList. Its type safe. and Also support insertion based on index.

With `ArrayList` you can use the index

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("first element");
list.Add("2nd element");

Console.Write(list[0]);
Console.Write(list[1]);

list[0] = "AAA - element"; //In actual its a modification, 
                           //if there is no element, there will b exception
list[1] = "BBB - element";
```

Remember you can't directly set element of a list based on an index.

Comment: I wouldn't call it insertion based on index, but modification based on index.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, I think you can't directly insert based on an index in a List, you can only Set/Get a value to an index. If it exists

Comment: if remove list.Add("first element");
list.Add("2nd element");, the script go wrong

Comment: That is because there are no items in the list if you remove Add statement. Thats what I said in the Edit, you can only modify/Get a value from the list based on the index, you can't insert using an index

Comment: @Habib - I know - that's why I called it modification based on index.

Comment: If help then if you need you can convert to array "list.ToArray()".

Answer (score 0):

al[1] needs to be created before you can use it via the indexer.

`al[1] = "bcd";` will result in an exception of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Remember array indexes start from zero.

If you want to overwrite it, it should be like this.

```
al[0] = "bcd";
```